# passing relative path in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have servlet that sends email:

```
 msg.setContent("<p>Please follow this <a href=\"http://localhost:8080/examples/RSI/ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp?action=<%=userID%>\"> link </a>to reset your password",
                        "text/html" );
```

Does anyone know how to make this link a relative path to ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp page?

Comment: At least you are sure there cannot be any problem of firewall to reach your link : localhost is allways the local machine ! But it would be surprising that **your** jsp were on **their** machine unless **you** are testing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put relative path in the email. Assuming that you mean, you don't want to hardcode the server url and you have access to `HTTPServletRequest request` object, you can use `request.getServerName()` or `request.getRequestURL()` methods to figure out server url.